# Python program to print prime numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have started learning python and I am stuck in this code

```
num=int(input("Enter the number"))
for i in range(2, num):
    if num%i==0:
        print("Not a prime number")
        break
        print("Prime Number")
```

When I enter the number which are not prime, then I am getting output as not a prime number but when I am entering the number that is prime I am getting the output as

```
Prime number
Prime number
Prime number
Prime number
Prime number
```

Comment: I think your indentation is not correct. Checkout `for .. else` in Python. `print("Prime Number")` should be in `else`.

Answer (score 5):

You should only print it once, for example like this:

```
num = int(input("Enter the number"))
for i in range(2, num):
    if num % i == 0:
        print("Not a prime number")
        break
else:
    print("Prime Number")
```

Answer (score 1):

The loop should check for all numbers and only then print not prime for example like this.

```
num=int(input("Enter the number"))
for i in range(2, num):
    if num%i == 0:
        print("Not a prime number")
        break
    if i > num/2:
        print("Prime Number")
        break
```

I would suggest you debug by including `print` statements that would help a beginner.

Comment: have you used for else here?

Answer (score 0):

check this out :

```
num=int(input("Enter the number"))
for i in range(2, num//2):   
    if (num % i) == 0: 
        print(num, "is not a prime number") 
        break
else: 
    print(num, "is a prime number")`
```

Answer (score 0):

The last statement should be managed carefully in this code. Due to this it print in loop and take care of the tabs you shift.